# Select columns by numbers - SELECT [m:n] FROM table_name

Tags: mysql

I have a database with many columns and sometimes I need to select quite a few.
Selecting all columns would be too much data. So lets say that:

```
DESC table_name
```

gives ordered column names, for example (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J....). Is it possible that instead:

```
SELECT C,D,E,F FROM table_name;
```

I do something like this:

```
SELECT [3:6] FROM table_name
```

I know it makes no difference in this example, but I need to select over 40 columns with long names.

Comment: look on http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,286477,286489#msg-286489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't `SELECT [3:6] FROM table_name`  What do you think this is, some kind of modern computer language with sequences and ranges as first class data types? :-) :-).   This is SQL.

You can, as a commenter pointed out, fetch the names of the columns in the table and then programmatically generate your SQL queries.  This is, of course, something a bunch of different data-access-object packages do automatically.

Comment: I know I can't use [3:6], but was hopping for something similar. I will look at your suggestions.